# Navigating a multi-step form using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, key-bindings

I have a 5 panel multi step form that uses divs `'previous'` and `'next'` to navigate through. I would like to make it so hitting a left arrow key acts as clicking the previous button, but hitting the right arrow key will act as hitting right.

I have this working.. Sort of.

I have bind(ed) my arrow keys correctly, but since it's going off of class name, it wants to tab through every single one of them. Is there a way to do it so it only activates the one that is on the `<fieldset>` currently displaying?

```
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
```

```
//binds left/right for navigation
$(window).bind('keydown', function(e){

    if (e.keyCode==37) {
        $(".previous").trigger("click");
    } else if (e.keyCode==39) {
        $(".next").trigger("click");
    };
});
```

Comment: Have you tried finding which field (and thus which fieldset) has the focus?

Comment: give id to fieldset and use ,  `$("#id input.previous")`  or  `$("fieldset input.previous")`

Comment: How would I go about that? Would I check it with `$("fieldset").is(":focus")` or would each one need a class name?

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is working already. I would suggest
 to have a different class name, for your particular interested elements, & trigger click on them only
 so that it does tab only those.

Best of luck.

(Mark this as answer if it serves your need)

Comment: I've already thought of doing this, but there has to be a way to do it that is a little more elegant than this.

Comment: Its elegant if you do like this, in your CSS:          .classname1, .classname2 {...}